# FAB button not showing drawable properly inside android studio layout editor

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I cannot seem to get the FAB button preview to work properly.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/email_icon"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

The dependency - `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'`

Preview

[image]

I have tried to change the drawable being shown to a normal vector image and also change `app:srcCompat` to `android:src` but no luck :(

I read that it may be a bug in the android studio - I have the 4.1.1 version installed.

Style/Theme file contents

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Kotlin" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/cyan</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/cyan_dark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>

    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

Color file contents

```
<resources>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="cyan">#006064</color>
    <color name="cyan_light">#428e92</color>
    <color name="cyan_dark">#00363a</color>
    <color name="green">#81c784</color>
    <color name="green_light">#b2fab4</color>
    <color name="green_dark">#519657</color>
</resources>
```

Manifest file contents

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Kotlin">

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/tip_time">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: A rebuild may be helpful.

Comment: please paste your style.xml and color file.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar I have done that. Also tried cleaning, rebuilding, and invalidating caches and restarting

Comment: @jeanlucrotolo Do you have two style file in your project that is style.xml and themes.xml ?

Comment: @VishalChauhan Yes but my style file is empty `<resources></resources>`. I am using the themes.xml only for now. I have tried to have use only the style.xml but I get the same issue

Comment: @jeanlucrotolo you code look perfect..please paste your android manifest file here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225927/discussion-between-jeanluc-rotolo-and-vishal-chauhan).

Answer (score 1):

Change material theme implementation to `'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'`. Because new release of Material Theme library is buggy. Simply restart Android Studio after gradle sync if problem not fixed.